# Error 419 (unknown status) en peticion POST con Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Según lo que he leído tengo problema de seguridad con el token.

Intento colocando esto:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

En mi cabecera encuentro esto:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: imagen]

¿Hay alguna manera de verificar que el token se esta cargando debidamente?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta esto:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

A mi me funciona enviando de la siguiente manera:

```
"_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
```

Ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('url') }}",
    data: {
        "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
    },
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        //Acciones si success
    },
    error: function () {
        //Acciones si error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Yo lo mando de forma diferente:

**html**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**js**

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '{{ route("registros.store") }}',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'folio_contrato': $('#folio_contrato').val(),
        'apellido_paterno': $('#apellido_paterno').val(),
        'apellido_materno': $('#apellido_materno').val(),
        'nombre': $('#nombre').val()
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('bloqueo botones');
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log('desbloqueo botones');
    },
    success: function (response) {
       console.log('ok!');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log('boo!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me paso eso hoy, el problema era un helper que hice. Algo no hice bien en los nombres del helper, volví a hacer todo el proceso con un nuevo nombre, (supongo que al anterior se lo cambié a mano) y se solucionó el problema.

Comment: Andres, gracias por proponer. Te recomiendo que la solución que propones la no la enuncies en términos genéricos. En tu caso dices que lo solucionaste cambiando el nombre de una clase tipo helper. Para que tu respuesta sea aceptada, deberías indicar lo mas exactamente posible, en el código que presenta Pablo, que es lo que él deberia hacer para solucionarlo. Si piensas que para solucionar la pregunta, falta infromación puedes hacerlo a través de comentarios a la misma pregunta.